# Cannot set x axis as dates in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

first time poster, long time lurker on the R questions...

I've finally been stumped for 48 hours,
and I'm coming to all of you beat; but hopefully not for long!

I have an irregular time series that I'm trying to plot with ggplot 2.
I would like for the breaks and labels to show only for the days where we have data.

The variable holding the date starts off as a factor read in from excel which I convert to class date:

```
Dataset[,BatchDateCol] <- as.Date(Dataset[,BatchDateCol],format="%m/%d/%y")
```

(this is part of a larger system, so I can't just read in the data differently)

I create a vector of the labels in the format I want:

```
Date_Vec <- c(history[,BatchDateCol])
Date_Vec <- format(Date_Vec, "%b %d")
```

I then aggregate around the days to get the means for each day:

```
history <- ddply(Dataset, BatchDateCol, function(z) colMeans(z[RawLocation]))
```

Now I want to plot it, to do that I find the column with the date, and the variable of interest:

```
ProductionDate <- grep(BatchDateCol,colnames(history))
Location <- grep(GGVar, colnames(history))
```

This is where the problem starts; I can create my plot just fine like this:

```
plot2 <- ggplot(history, aes_string(x=history[ProductionDate], y=history[(Location)]))
plot2 + xlab(XAxisName) +ylab(GGVar)+geom_line(aes_string(y=means), linetype="dashed") 
plot2 + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~poly(x,1))
```

but when I try to add dates to the x axis I get errors, no plot, or no breaks+labels.
These 2 commands draw the right plot, but with no breaks or labels:

```
scale_x_continuous(labels=Date_Vec, breaks=c(1:length(history[,BatchDateCol])),
expand=c(.01,0))
```

&

```
scale_x_continuous(labels=Date_Vec, breaks=c(1:length(history[,BatchDateCol])),
limits=c(min(as.numeric(history[,BatchDateCol])),
max(as.numeric(history[,BatchDateCol]))))
```

This command draws the right breaks and labels but no plot(...!)

```
scale_x_continuous(labels=Date_Vec, 
limits=c(1,length(history[,BatchDateCol])), expand=c(.01,0))
```

and when I plot it with only:

```
scale_x_continuous(labels=Date_Vec, expand=c(.01,0))
```

it *sometimes* works, but most of the time I get:

> Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale, major) : Breaks and labels are different lengths

If I don't specify labels  in scale_x_continuous, I get the numeric form of the dates (days since 1970 or whatever) that I want (though I'm not sure its plotting it in the right spot), but I can't figure out how to modify that either.

Finally I've tried changing scale_x_continuous to scale_x_date:

```
plot2 + scale_x_date(expand=c(.01,0))
```

which returns an error: (I've tried placing a few different parameters in the ())

> Error : Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

I have tried leaving Dataset[,BatchDateCol] as a factor or character vector which also does not work.

SO.... I'm at a total loss and feel unbelievably defeated :(

**EDIT**

ProductionDate is a quoted variable defined here:
`QC_Process <- function(Dataset, GGVar, XAxisName="TIME SERIES", BatchDateCol, BatchNum=-1, startdate=NULL, enddate=NULL) {...`

So I can't use $ to access the var. Also, I already apply unique right after the var is defined (`history <- unique(history)')

(This is production code for a big R Shiny app, and belongs to my employer, so I can't post to much of it... )

When I use `breaks=(history[,ProductionDate])`  I get:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

and When I use 'breaks=(history[ProductionDate])' I get:

> Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

`print(history[ProductionDate])` returns:

> Date.of.Consumption
>
> 1          2012-03-24
>
> 2          2013-03-11
>
> 3          2013-05-10
>
> 4          2013-05-11
>
> 5          2013-05-13
>
> 6          2013-05-16

Comment: Instead of print(history[ProductionDate]), show us `dput(history)`, or `dput(head(history))` if it's got a lot of rows. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/903061) for other tips on making reproducible questions.

Comment: the output of `dput(head(history))` is:
`structure(list(Date.of.Consumption = structure(c(15423, 15775, 
15835, 15836, 15838, 15841), class = "Date"), Sugars = c(1.33333333333333, 
0, 1, 2.8, 2, 2.5)), .Names = c("Date.of.Consumption", "Sugars"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I'm sorry, I took another look, but I don't have `Dataset`, `BatchDateCol`, `Location`, `RawLocation`, `GGVar`, etc., so your code is completely un-runnable and un-diagnosable. If you can make a **small** and **reproducible** example, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by setting

```
scale_x_continuous(labels=Date_Vec, Breaks=(as.numeric(history[,ProductionDate])))
```

Still not sure why it works, and the labels sometimes overlap when I have consecutive dates,
but it is progress!

Answer (score 3):

`scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(history$ProductionDate))` should do it (but I can't quite replicate your code, because I don't have the original `Dataset`, so I haven't been able to test this solution.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete comment, and thank you for your help!
I have added an edit to the code above. I'm truly appreciative that you are taking the time to work with not perfectly reproducible code!